# How to create dynamically in a form using previous field values

Tags: html, jsp

I need to create a form where I input 2 dates and as 3 rd input I need to create a drop down list having a range of values found from database using the dates entered bt I need all these in a single form without using submit

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please provide some code of what you have tried so far? This makes it easier for people to get your idea and help you.

Comment: I need a form like this date1:    Date 2:  drop down list  using values computed from date 1 and 2 finally a submit that directs me to next page

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

`

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date1" placeholder="From" />
<input type="date" name="date" id="date2" placeholder="To"/>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="selectdate1" id="resdate1" placeholder="date1"/>
<input type="text" name="selectdate2" id="resdate2" placeholder="date2"/>
```

`

```
$(function() {

     $("#date1").on("change",function(){
        var from = $(this).val();
        var to = $(this).val();
        //alert(from);
         $('#resdate1').val(from);
     });
     $("#date2").on("change",function(){
       var to = $(this).val();
      // alert(to);
        $('#resdate2').val(to);
    });
  });
```

Demo here  https://jsfiddle.net/palavamsi09/3r9u26xy/5/

Comment: Thanks for your response:) can I call a java function inside this function?